# Нужно удалить символы из строки

Tags: javascript

```js
function deleteSymbol(text, symbol) {
    text = prompt("Введите текст");
    symbol = prompt("Введите символы");

    let textArr = text.split([]);
    let symbolArr = symbol.split([]);

    for(let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < symbolArr.length; j++) {
            if (textArr[i] === symbolArr[j]) {
                textArr.slice(i,j);  
                // Скорее всего ошибка здесь,но не понятно
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(textArr);
    console.log(symbolArr);
}

let functionResult = deleteSymbol();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `x.slice(i, j)` не удаляет ничего. Он возвращает массив элементов другого массива с индексами от `i` включая до `j` не включая: **[i; j)** .

Метод `x.splice(i, j)` может как удалять, так и добавлять элементы в массив. Погуглите.

Так и не понял зачем вы создавали `text` и `symbol` как аргументы функции, если можно и нужно просто дописать `let` перед присваиванием. И ещё, в метод `split` можно передавать пустую строку, т.к. если передавать пустой массив, то он приводится к пустой строке.

```
function deleteSymbol() {
            let text = prompt("Введите текст");
            let symbol = prompt("Введите символы");

            let textArr = text.split("");
            let symbolArr = symbol.split("");

            for(let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
                for(let j = 0; j < symbolArr.length; j++) {
                    if (textArr[i] === symbolArr[j]) {
                        textArr.splice(i, 1);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(textArr);
            console.log(symbolArr);
            return textArr.join("");
        }

let functionResult = deleteSymbol();
console.log(functionResult);
```

Comment: Работает,но не все символы удаляет. hello world когда ввожу и удаляю l и d. Результат получается helo wor

Comment: Исправил свою ошибку. После удаления элемента остальные элементы сдвигаются, поэтому в данном случае нужно вычитать из `i` единицу после каждого удаления.